# TypeError: this.listService.addItem(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, mean-stack

Hi I have been working on this for the last two days and cannot figure out where my error is. I have a simple html form and when I click the add button it should add my input to the mongo database and then display it on the website. However, I am getting the .subscribe is not a function TypeError.

This is my first MEAN stack application so all this is pretty new to me. Let me know if there is any additional info needed I may have left out. I was trying to use the info I learned from the angular.io tutorial for my angular code and another tutorial for my comprehensive MEAN stack app. I found that my MEAN stack tutorial is using outdated angular syntax so I wonder if that's where my issue is.

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="add">
    <input class="newItem" #newListInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="input" placeholder="Enter new items here">
    <!-- (click) passes input value to addList() and then clears the input -->
    <button id="addListButton" (click)="addList(newListInput.value); newListInput.value=''">Add</button>
  </div>
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { ListService } from '../../services/list.service';
import { List } from '../../list';
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;

  lists: List[];

  @Input() input;

  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private listService: ListService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  getLists(): void {
    this.listService.getAllTodos()
      .subscribe(list => this.lists = list);
  }

  addList(newItem): void {
    const newTodo = { item: newItem, completed: false };
      this.listService.addItem(newTodo).subscribe(data => {
          this.lists.push(data);
      });
  }
```

list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { List } from '../list';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class ListService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllTodos(): Observable<List[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<List[]>('http://localhost:3000/todos/lists')
  }

  addItem(newTodo) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/todos/dashboard'), newTodo, httpOptions)
      .map(res => res.json());
  } 
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your dev tools, and inspect your variables. Also, if you're using `HttpClient` (and *not* the older/deprecated `Http`), then the `.map(res => res.json());` is unnecessary, just FYI - because HttpClient's post/get/put/etc return json by default.

Comment: There seems to be an uneven number of parentheses in your `addItem` function. Is the closing one directly after your URL correct?

Comment: OMG @user184994! yes i just also found that error. Thanks!!!

Comment: @matmo thanks for the feedback. So what exactly is and how do I set a breakpoint in my dev tools?

Comment: @CuongVo If you plan on working with javascript in the browser, definitely watch a few of these videos: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=chrome+dev+tools+tutorial .